# Charts drill down as 'year to months for different cities' in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on Tableau for rainfall data.
I have a cumulative rainfall data for a year (and the months respectively) of different cities.

And I prepared a tableau barchart for the annual rainfall data.
So, if I hover/click my cursor on any of the bar then a line chart which carries the months of that particular city need to be visualized.

Please suggest.

Comment: What did you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You have to using compulsory Action Filter.

choose dashboard menu -> Action->add action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create another worksheet with the line chart month view you would like to see.

Then go to Worksheet>Actions>

Add Action > Filter and Select how you want it to run (hover/select)

Select your new worksheet as the target sheet

Target filters on the year which displays the months you want in the new view

You might need to mess around with these setting to get it how you want exactly but an action is the way to go.

Comment: It's good but where the problem arises is I have 450 cities to work with. So is there any other suggestion where I can run easily without many sheets.

Comment: Add a city quick filter single value drop down.  Then you can just type or select a single city and apply that filter to both sheets.

Comment: Action fires a query and execution of query will depend on the volume of data, in such cases eliminating data using filters is a good option. Make city as a filter for 2 or more sheets, you can select multiple cities as well.